# How To Iterate Over A Timespan and Calculate some Values in a Dataframe using Python?

Tags: python, date, for-loop, sum, slice

I have a dataset like below

[image]

```
data = {'ReportingDate':['2013/5/31','2013/5/31','2013/5/31','2013/5/31','2013/5/31','2013/5/31',
                         '2013/6/28','2013/6/28',
                         '2013/6/28','2013/6/28','2013/6/28'],
        'MarketCap':[' ',0.35,0.7,0.875,0.7,0.35,' ',1,1.5,0.75,1.25],
       'AUM':[3.5,3.5,3.5,3.5,3.5,3.5,5,5,5,5,5],
       'weight':[' ',0.1,0.2,0.25,0.2,0.1,' ',0.2,0.3,0.15,0.25]}
 
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.set_index('Reporting Date',inplace=True)
df
```

Just a sample of a 8000 rows dataset.

ReportingDate starts from 2013/5/31 to 2015/10/30.
It includes data of all the months during the above period. But Only the last day of each month.
The first line of each month has two missing data. I know that

- the sum of weight for each month is equal to 1
- weight*AUM is equal to MarketCap

I can use the below line to get the answer I want, for only one month

```
a= (1-df["2013-5"].iloc[1:]['weight'].sum())
b= a* AUM
df.iloc[1,0]=b
df.iloc[1,2]=a
```

How can I use a loop to get the data for the whole period? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using `pandas.DataFrame.groupby`:

```
# If whitespaces are indeed whitespaces, not nan
df = df.replace("\s+", np.nan, regex=True)

# If not already datatime series
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

s = df["weight"].fillna(1) - df.groupby(df.index.date)["weight"].transform(sum)
df["weight"] = df["weight"].fillna(s)
df["MarketCap"] = df["MarketCap"].fillna(s * df["AUM"])
```

Note: This assumes that dates are always only the last day so that it is equivalent to grouping by year-month. If not so, try:

```
s = df["weight"].fillna(1) - df.groupby(df.index.strftime("%Y%m"))["weight"].transform(sum)
```

Output:

```
               MarketCap  AUM  weight
ReportingDate                        
2013-05-31         0.350  3.5    0.10
2013-05-31         0.525  3.5    0.15
2013-05-31         0.700  3.5    0.20
2013-05-31         0.875  3.5    0.25
2013-05-31         0.700  3.5    0.20
2013-05-31         0.350  3.5    0.10
2013-06-28         0.500  5.0    0.10
2013-06-28         1.000  5.0    0.20
2013-06-28         1.500  5.0    0.30
2013-06-28         0.750  5.0    0.15
2013-06-28         1.250  5.0    0.25
```

Comment: Thank you. as my ReportingDate's YEAR also change from 2013 to 2015, should I groupby on month and year? I have 2013-05  2014-05 2015-05

Comment: I am geting this error on the second line;  TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str

Comment: I think some of your elements (i'm guessing the blanks?) are string. Can them to `nan`. Check my update.